# images not working in IE but fine for firefox

Tags: java, javascript

I have an image which works fine in Firefox but IE gives problem: my source code is:

```
  buffer.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" ><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/\n");
  buffer.append("if (document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value == \"false\") {\n");
  buffer.append("document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value = \"true\";\n");
  buffer.append("setTimeout('document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submit()', 100);\n}else{\n");
  buffer.append("document.getElementById(\"toHide\").style.display=\"none\";\n}/*-->]]>*/</script>");
```

I can give java script as:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> <!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/if (document.getElementById("safeForm30").submitted.value == "false") {document.getElementById("safeForm30").submitted.value = "true";setTimeout('document.getElementById("safeForm30").submit()', 100);}else{document.getElementById("toHide").style.display="none";}/*-->]]>*/</SCRIPT>
```

Please let me know what is the issue here?

Comment: Java != Javascript. Which do you actually want? You also need to post a lot more information about your problem for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I don't see an image in your code? Can you show the code you are using to embed it?

Comment: @unholysampler obviously the code is using Java or another server language to create the javascript string

Comment: @mplungjan: The op looked very different when I posted that. Look at the revisions and see what was initially posted.

Comment: In your first line of your Java you have an \n after the `<!--` but there's no linebreak in the script sample - is this getting emitted or not? I've seen browsers be sensitive to having a line-break after the `<!--` (but I can't remember if that was IE or not). Is it running any script, e.g. if you put an alert in does that get hit?

Comment: Anyway no need to use <!-- at all. It is used to hide JS from old browsers and your <!CDATA will do that for the same ancient browsers too. The problem is if you do NOT breakline after the <!-- then the whole line will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this (which still does not have an image)

```
  buffer.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" ><![CDATA[\n");
  buffer.append("if (document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value == \"false\") {\n");
  buffer.append("  document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submitted.value = \"true\";\n");
  buffer.append("  setTimeout('document.getElementById(\"").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submit()', 100);\n}\n");
  buffer.append("\nelse{\ndocument.getElementById(\"toHide\").style.display=\"none\";\n}]]></script>");
```